# microsoft hpc visual studio error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mpi, hpc

everybody! I want to work with some mpi.h library in visual studio c++ 2010, but when i call function of the library, for example MPI_Init(), it gives me "error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol". In addition, compiler do not give the error on  #include . How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you linked your .lib file using #pragma comment or project settings (linker->input) ?

Comment: @Pavel You are doing `#include <mpi.h>`?

Comment: I add msmpi.lib to the linker->include->additional dependencies

Comment: @Pavel linker->include?

Comment: Yes i included mpi.h of course.

Comment: i think linker->input

Comment: i add #pragma comment(lib, "msmpi"), it doesnt work

Comment: @Pavel Does it give same error?

Comment: Error is the same, as it was, i.e. "error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps in below link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hpctrekker/archive/2009/06/26/examples-of-linking-in-msmpi-library.aspx

Comment: This link is helpful, however the post would be more valuable if you could paste the pertinent text in your answer as well.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is very useful, but nothing helps. May be it is compatibility problem, or something else - I don't know. I am gonna reinstall visual studio, hpc and all this staff again, may be it would help.